# How to make a mouse cursor to point to a window?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

Is there a way to automatically/by default set the mouse cursor to point inside a newly created window (using for e.g. the `CreateWindow` function)? I know that for keyboard input there is a `SetFocus()` function, but haven't found a similar function for a mouse.

Comment: Not sure what problem you are trying to solve, but to `Set` the `Cursor` `Pos`ition, you call [SetCursorPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcursorpos).

Comment: @IInspectable I'd just like to set the cursor centered on the newly create window. Is it RALLY such a complicated task? Can You provide a code please?

Answer (score 1):

As @IInspectable said, the following is the code implementation.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcNOP(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        RECT rcClient;
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rcClient);
        int x = rcClient.left + (rcClient.right - rcClient.left) / 2;
        int y = rcClient.top + (rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top) / 2;
        SetCursorPos(x, y);
    }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```